# Flutter Vertical Scrollable Drawer

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I would like to create something like [this](https://dribbble.com/shots/6120171-Groceries-Shopping-App-Interaction)

I have a page with a list of products and I would like to make visible the "Cart" part only when I scroll to the bottom of the screen and when I click on a product and be able to swipe up to navigate to the cart screen.

A solution could be making a `Stack` with two `Container` inside and have a variable that represent the current % of screen of the first Container (products) and moving them with the widget `Positioned`. So when I scroll to the bottom, I can raise up the product container and reveal the cart container and same thing when I swipe up the first container.

[This](https://github.com/flutter-ui-challenges/flutter_challenge_googlemaps) is an example of the vertical drawer with % and `Positioned`

Is there a better solution?

**EDIT**

I did it, but it's not very smooth

The structure:

```
CustomScrollView()
|
|____SliverList()
|    |
|    |____Visibility() => Container() //Products list
|    |
|    |____Visibility() => Container() //Bottom Container with Borders
|
|____SliverList()
     |
     |____Visibility() => Container() //Bottom Cart part
     |
     |____Visibility() => Container() //Cart Screen
```

Starting with only `Products List` visible

When user clicks on a product, `Bottom Container` and `Bottom Cart` will be visible

I also put a `GestureDetector()` in `Bottom Container` and `Bottom Cart`.

With `onVerticalDragUpdate` if the user swipe up `(details.delta.dy < 0)`:

```
_controller.animateTo(
                                             
    _controller.position.maxScrollExtent,
    duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
    curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
);
```

And set visibility of `Bottom Cart` to false and set the `Cart Screen` visibility to true

As well I can might set the visibility of `Products List` to false, but this will cause a bug in the scroll animation so I set the mobile screen to only show `Bottom Container` and `Cart Screen` with the screen width (I didn't test it on other devices, this may be an error on ui) and I also block the scrolling with `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` in the `CustomScrollView`

On Swipe down on the `Bottom Container`, I set the visibility of `Cart Screen` to false, `Bottom Cart` to true and set `CustomScrollView` physics to `AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()` and made a scroll animation:

```
_controller.animateTo(
                                             
    _controller.position.maxScrollExtent,
    duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
    curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
);
```

That's not very smooth because a better animation could be moving down the `Cart Screen` with `Positioned`, instead of making it invisible

Comment: Flutter has a widget BottomSheet for such functionality, have you tried it?

Comment: @ASADHAMEED BottomSheet can't be the solution, check the first link

Comment: for such complex animated layouts check either `Flow` or `CustomMultiChildLayout` widgets

Comment: check our sliver widgets I think that's what they do